# How to upload image in windows azure mobile service from android.?

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am new in android I am using windows azure mobile service and I am Inserting Text data successfully but now I want to Upload Image in windows azure mobile service. I know its is possible by Azure Storage I have seen this post http://chrisrisner.com/Storing-Images-from-Android-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services but its confusing can anyone tell me simple step by step process to save image in windows azure mobile service.

I will be Very Grateful for you

Comment: Please tell what you found confusing. I found confusing that in the provided link i could not find the code for the `SaveTodoTask`. Only some json code for doInBackground. So i do not the url where the POST would go to. What would be so special posting to Windows Azure?

Comment: i also did not find code for saveTodoTask. have you run application with out any error.?  i have posted in azure forum as well waiting for the solution

Comment: I don't understand that if you can send text data (in one key value pair i think) (and knowing the url) that you can't send two variables of wich one contains the base64 encoded image.

Answer (score 2):

The page you're looking at does not use the best recommended approach for storing image data with Azure Mobile Services.  Instead, you should connect to Azure Blob Storage when you want to store a file.  You can see a full tutorial of connecting to Blob Storage and saving files from an Android app here: http://chrisrisner.com/Android-and-Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage.  Essentially the steps you follow are:

1. Create a table script / custom API in your mobile service that will save your data as well as generate a Secure Access Signature (SAS) URL from Blob Storage.
2. Call that endpoint from your mobile app.
3. Return the SAS URL from the endpoint.
4. When you get the URL back on your mobile app, use that URL to post your image file.

The way that older approach uses is to convert the image data into a format that can be stored using Azure Mobile Services SQL Database.  This does work, however, it's very inefficient.

Comment: There is also an Android SDK for Azure Blob Storage that will make the connection easier: https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-android